# QListView not displaying header

Tags: c++, qt

This is another QListView isn't displaying a header. I've reviewed about a dozen other similar questions, and none of them clued me in.

I'm trying to make a generic template as such:

```
template <class T>
class GenericItemModel: public QAbstractTableModel {
public:
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const override {
        cout << "GenericItemModel::rowCount() returning " << vector.size() << endl;
        return vector.size();
    }

    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &) const override {
        cout << "GenericItemModel::columnCount() returning " << columns.size() << endl;
        return columns.size();
    }

    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const override {
        cout << "headerData() for section: " << section << endl;
        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole
            && orientation == Qt::Horizontal
            && section >= 0
            && static_cast<size_t>(section) < columns.size())
        {
            return columns[section]->header;
        }

        return QVariant();
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override {
    ...
    }
};
```

I've omitted all the column / data handling. Output during startup is:

```
GenericItemModel::columnCount() returning 1
GenericItemModel::rowCount() returning 0
GenericItemModel::rowCount() returning 0
GenericItemModel::columnCount() returning 1
GenericItemModel::rowCount() returning 0
GenericItemModel::rowCount() returning 0
```

But it never calls `headerData()`, and the header doesn't display. I suspect I'm doing something wrong in `rowCount()`.

Suggestions?

Comment: I think you should avoid using templates with `QObject` sub classes.

Comment: As stated in the [QListView documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#details), "This view does not display horizontal or vertical headers; to display a list of items with a horizontal header, use QTreeView instead."

Comment: @Simpsons Thank you. I switched to A QTreeView, grabbed my old demo model to try to figure out what else I needed, and its now working.